# System.DateTime.ParseExact : unrecognized format string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timestamp, iso8601

```
var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101T000000Z", "YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
```

This makes no sense to me as `YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ` is ISO-8601 `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` with the special formatting characters removed.

Comment: I've edited your question. See why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `YYYY` and `DD` are not a valid format specifiers. Use `yyyy` and `dd` instead, and if you want to use 24-hour time, use `HH`:

```
var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101T000000Z", "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also note that the `Z` here is interpreted as a literal `Z` character. It's not a substitute for `z`, the timezone specifier.

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your dateformat is incorrect.

`YYYY` should be `yyyy` and `DD` should be `dd`

The following full format should work

`yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ`

such as

```
var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101T000000Z", "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

MSDN For custom formatting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx